# Ajax dropdown list not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on a dynamic site in which a user can search for doctors by proving the location and specialist as shown here: [image: This is my main page]

This is my main page code:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHint(str){
        if(str.length==0){
            document.getElementById("ddlstate").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("ddlstate").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET","getstate.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(str){
        if(str.length==0){
            document.getElementById("ddldis").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("ddldis").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET","getdis.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlHttp.send();
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
        <center>
            <img src="images/placeholder-2.png"/ width="50px;"><br>
            <label>Location</label>
        </center>
        <select id="ddlcnt" onchange="showHint(this.value)" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">-----Select Location-----</option>
            <?php 
                error_reporting(0);
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("doctor_db",$con);
                $sql="select * from location_tb";
                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ar[0];?>"><?php echo $ar[1];?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 form-group">
        <center>
            <img src="images/surgeon.png"/ width="50px;">
            <!--<img src="images/stethoscope.png"/ width="50px;">--><br>
            <!-- <label>Doctors</label>-->
            <label>Specialty</label>
        </center>
        <select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate"  class="form-control">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 mrg_less">
            <center>
                <img src="images/stethoscope.png"/ width="50px;"><br>
                <label>Doctors</label>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 mrg_less">
            <select id="ddldis" name="ddldis" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button class="search" name="search" id="search" type="submit"><i class="flaticon-magnifier-tool"></i></button>
```

**getstate.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>AJAX</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <option value="0">-----select specialist-----</option>
            <?php
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("doctor_db",$con);
                $q=$_GET["q"];
                $sql="select * from specialty_tb where lid='".$q."'";
                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<option value=".$ar[0].">".$ar[1]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**getdis.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <option value="0">-----select doctor-----</option>
            <?php
                $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                mysql_select_db("doctor_db",$con);
                $q=$_GET["q"];
                $sql="select * from doctor_details where sid='".$q."'";
                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                    echo "<option value=".$ar[0].">".$ar[1]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

These are my tables

[image: location_tb] , [image: specialty_tb] [image: doctor_details]

The problem is when I select the location from the list I am able to get the specialists from that location using the location id. But I am not able to get the list of doctors.

For eg:- if I select the location as Kannur, I get all the specialists from Kannur as given in the table and if I select a specialist, say, Anesthesiologists, I am not able to get the doctors list who are Anesthesiologists. As per the data entered in doctor_details, i should be getting 'doctor 1' in the third list as per the sid provided.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: pl attached sql file

Comment: You are doing *two grave mistakes*. One, you are using `mysql` interface, which is almost thrown into the dumpster. Use `mysqli` instead. Two you have set `error_reporting(0);` which completely blocks your debugging opportunities in php.

Comment: Also please remove the first line from the snippet after inserting if it is not runnable AFTER clicking TIDY if the code can be tidied. As you can see, the script tags did not belong in the JavaScript panel

Comment: And a third mistake I would add to the list here, is that ugly mixture of HTML code and processing logic to begin with - keyword https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model

Comment: Your `getstate.php` and `getdis.php` scripts both return a complete HTML document - doctype, html and body element, the lot. You are trying to stuff those whole documents into your `select` elements, by assigning what these requests returned unmodified to their innerHTML ... of course that is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only change in this line

```
 <select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate"  class="form-control"  
onchange="showHide(this.value)" >
```

You need to add onchange event and it will work.

Comment: thank you so much. it worked. i forgot to add onchange="showHide(this.value)" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append string and then add in select via javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <option value="0">-----select doctor-----</option>
    <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("doctor_db",$con);
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    $sql="select * from doctor_details where sid='".$q."'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    $option = '';
    while($ar=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
     $option .= "<option value=".$ar[0].">".$ar[1]."</option>";
    }
    echo $option;
    ?>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
need to take another div tag in index.php: 
<div id="ddlstate_div">
<select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate" class="form-control">
/////
</select>
 </div>
```

and change in ajax showHint function: document.getElementById("ddlstate").innerHTML replaced by document.getElementById("ddlstate_div").innerHTML

```
Add below tag in getstate.php:

    <select id="ddlstate" name="ddlstate" onchange="showHide(this.value)" class="form-control">


        </select>
```

Comment: give us your feedback.

Comment: thank you so much. it worked. i forgot to add onchange="showHide(this.value)" :)